# Possible to get Blockchain bitcoins over to Stripe or Paypal?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, paypal, money-transfer

I'm new to the Bitcoin world. I accepted a Blockchain transfer over the weekend as payment for something. I'm wondering if it's possible to get my Blockchain Bitcoins (well, fraction of a bit coin) over to my Stripe account or PayPal account?

Comment: Welcome!  You need to understand that bitcoin is its own currency.  You can't have bitcoins in PayPal, because PayPal doesn't use that currency.  You will first need to convert bitcoin into a fiat currency (USD, EUR, CNY, GBP, etc...) that the third party service supports, and then transfer *that* money into that other service.  Converting to other currencies is not a function of bitcoin, itself, just like converting to euros isn't a function of dollars, themselves.  You have to find a service that will trade you fiat for your bitcoins.

Comment: This might help get you started:  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a crypto currency exchange to move funds from one currency to another.

For example you can sell Bitcoins for USD or other fiat currencies and payout the amount to a credit card or a bank account.